# SOAP: Unexpected internal error

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using php to request SOAP request. Below is the code. I am generating security pass phrase in this function : `generateWSSecurityHeader`. That one is ok. I don't know what else wrong in below method.

Web-service URL: https://ifs-uat.ca.equifax.com/uru/soap/ut/canadav2?wsdl

```
    $soap_client = new SoapClient("https://ifs-uat.ca.equifax.com/uru/soap/ut/canadav2?wsdl");
    $functions = $soap_client->__getFunctions();
    $soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($this->generateWSSecurityHeader($username, $password, "PasswordText"));

    $all_names = array('FirstName'=>"PERFUME",
                       'LastName'=>"TESTSWEET");

    $all_addresses = array('AddressLine'=>"109 ALBERT ST NE",
                           'City'=>"AIRDRIE",
                           'Province'=>"AB",
                           'PostalCode'=>"T4B0R5"
                           );

    $hybrid_address = array('HybridAddress'=>$all_addresses);
    $identity = array('Name'=>$all_names,
                      'Address'=>$hybrid_address
                      );

    $language = array('Language'=>'English');

    $initial_request = array('Identity'=>$identity,
                             'ProcessingOptions'=>$language
                             );

    try{
        $test = $soap_client->__soapCall('startTransaction', array('InitialRequest'=>$initial_request));
    }
    catch(SoapFault $fault){
        die("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})");
    }

    echo $soap_client->__getLastRequest();
```

**ERROR**

> SOAP Fault: (faultcode: soap:Server, faultstring: Unexpected internal error)

Comment: It's an unexpected internal error on server side. Not much we can help you with that. You will have to consult web service owner for more details.

Comment: I have contacted them already? Any how we can identify this by the web-service? I mean data-type or any missing thing?

Comment: IMHO, they should identify the problem and fix it or tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Furgas: They are saying that transaction is not being submitted to their server. There is a problem from our side.

Comment: It's unlikely. Check if you're getting any response with `echo htmlentities($soap_client->__getLastResponse());`. If so, then they are getting your request.